# When are views and view controllers initialized/instantiated in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming. I wonder when all the views and view controllers will be created.

At the time when the app launched all views and their controllers are created

or

when the view become active (displayed on the screen), it and its controller will be created(also, when it becomes inactive, it will be deallocated)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is neither really, but it depends on the structure of your app. The views are not created until you reference them, or the view is about to be put on screen. The controllers though can be instantiated at different times, that could be well before the view is created. For instance, when using a tab bar controller, all of the controllers are instantiated right after the tab bar controller itself, but only the view of the tab at index 0 is created and displayed. The other views are not loaded until you click on one of the other tabs. With segues, the controllers are created when the segue is called, and the views are loaded shortly thereafter (but after prepareForSegue is called in the calling class which is why you can't reference any of the destination controller's views in that method).

The view controllers and their views will be deallocated when there is no longer any strong  pointer to them. Again, when that happens depends on how your app is set up. For instance, with a navigation controller, when you push to another controller, the initial one is not on screen any more, but the navigation controller has a strong reference to it, so it is not deallocated. However, when you pop a view controller (off the navigation controller's stack), it will be deallocated, unless you keep a pointer to it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something happens in main() that initializes the app delegate when your app first starts. The app delegate initializes the window object which manages displaying content to your screen. The app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is the entry point into our app's logic. Here is where you can initialize and set your root view controller although it's taken care of for you, especially if you're using storyboard.

After the root view controller is initialized it'll go through a series of steps setting up it's views.

```
viewDidLoad()
viewWillAppear()
viewDidAppear()
viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

are some events you can respond to as it's being set up. I assume somewhere between viewDidAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews is when similar events are called for that view controller's subviews.

```
viewWillDisappear()
viewDidDisappear()
viewDidUnLoad()
```

are the other events of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using StoryBoards, the root view controller defined in it is the view that will be loaded at app launch after that, you control the flow of the application yourself with a navigation controller for example.

For controlling the life cycle of your views, your controllers and the app, the OS will send messages to your classes that represent events. These can be events of the app launching, the view appearing on the screen or a class being instantiated.

Here are a few examples:

- When your app first launches, the OS will call `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate.
- When a viewControlles's View is about to appear on the screen, the OS will call `viewWillAppear()` on the viewController.
- When you create a view from the storyBoard, the method `initWithCoder:` get called on the view's class.

Here are some docs that explain it better: [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [View Controller Programming Guide: Resource Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html).

Comment: Any other way I can use to design my UI other than story board? Thanks!